# Getting .NET Core SDK not located error when I open a script in VS Code in Unity3D. All solutions on Google only work for Windows and not Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, visual-studio-code, dotnet, unity3d

> The .NET Core SDK cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be
> enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path.

[This is what the popup screen looks like in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjawT.png)

That's the popup I get at the bottom right whenever I open a .cs script in VSCode inside Unity3D. It doesn't interfere with the code completion or the execution of the program but I can't understand why I am getting this error since I followed the steps [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux) to install dotnet on Ubuntu 20.04. I also installed mono-complete by executing the following command in console:

```
sudo apt install mono-complete
```

But still VSCode inside Unity3D can't seem to locate dotnet SDK. I can confirm that dotnet SDK is installed on my system because whenever I check the version of dotnet SDK, I get the following:

```
muhammadmehdi@IITPAVISLW100:~$ dotnet --list-sdks
5.0.201 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/116/sdk]
muhammadmehdi@IITPAVISLW100:~$
```

And I also checked this inside the VSCode terminal:

```
muhammadmehdi@IITPAVISLW100:~/ellipsoid_visualization$ dotnet --list-sdks
5.0.201 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/116/sdk]
muhammadmehdi@IITPAVISLW100:~/ellipsoid_visualization$
```

So, it seems to be recognized inside the VSCode terminal but then why am I getting that popu message? I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077229/switch-between-dotnet-core-sdk-versions/42078060#42078060) but no luck.

EDIT: I added the following to my bashrc

```
export DOTNET_ROOT=/snap/dotnet-sdk/current
```

Still getting the same popup. **Is VSCode looking for dotnet SDK some place else? If so, where is VSCode looking for it?**

Answer (score 0):

A reboot should do the charm. However, there are a few issues with snap installation. Installing dotnet through APT worked for me without a reboot. [Dotnet SDK Ubuntu](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu)